# Separate and display bitmap from a socket stream

Tags: c++

How do I separate and display bitmap images from a continuous socket stream of multiple images? Below codes will save and display a single image when there's only one bmp received. How can I separate and display images when the socket stream contains multiple bitmap images (e.g BM .... BM .... BM...) ?

```
DWORD WINAPI CServerDlg::ThreadSocket( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    CServerDlg *pThis = (CServerDlg *)lpParam;

    SOCKET server;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaret = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData );
    if( wsaret != 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in local;
    local.sin_family = AF_INET; //Address family
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Wild card IP address
    local.sin_port = htons((u_short)8888); //port to use

    server = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if( server == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if( bind( server, (sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local) ) != 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if( listen( server, 10 ) != 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET_STREAM_FILE_INFO     StreamFileInfo;
    memset( &StreamFileInfo, 0, sizeof(SOCKET_STREAM_FILE_INFO) );
    SOCKET client;
    sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof( from );
    while( pThis->m_bListen )
    {
        char temp[1024];
        memset( temp, 0, 1024 );
        client = accept( server, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen );
        int iLen = recv( client, temp, sizeof(SOCKET_STREAM_FILE_INFO), 0 );
        if( iLen == sizeof(StreamFileInfo) )
        {
            memcpy( &StreamFileInfo, temp, sizeof(StreamFileInfo) );
            CFile destFile( StreamFileInfo.szFileTitle, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::typeBinary);
            UINT dwRead = 0;
            while( dwRead < StreamFileInfo.nFileSizeLow )
            {
                memset(temp,0,1024);
                UINT dw = recv( client, temp, 1024, 0 );
                destFile.Write(temp, dw);
                dwRead += dw;
            }
            destFile.Close();

            pThis->LoadPicture( StreamFileInfo.szFileTitle );   // Display image in a dialog box
        }
        closesocket(client);
    }
    closesocket(server);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `memset` before receiving, as the `recv` call will write into it anyway. Also, you should always check for errors or closed connection when calling `recv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bitmap format described here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Includes a file size field in the header. You can read that for each bitmap and know where the end of the current bitmap is.

Comment: The length of each image is included in the header. The problem with the above code is all images will be saved continuously as one binary file.

Comment: i know bitmap binary starts with "BM" (0×42 0x4D), how can i locate it, then extract it from the stream? how do i read "0×42 0x4D"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a protocol that differentiates between the different images.

A simple one that send a header (containing the size (in bytes) of the image, and possibly image type), followed by the actual image data is enough.

Comment: I am sending continuous stream with a fixed length of bitmap images. The length of each image is also sent to the server before each image is sent, and it's also included in the header of each image.

Comment: @boogiedoll Fixed size, or having the size being sent as a header, is enough. If all data in the stream is of a fixed length, you _know_ how much to read each time, and read exactly that.

Comment: how do I read that fixed length of file? do i read directly from the buffer? or save is as a file first then display?